# Button event and states

Tags: c#, events, button

I have a Windows Form in C# with 4 buttons with different states that I use as a menu.

What is the best way to use/implement the different button states.

Normal --> Mouse Enter, Mouse Leave and Mouse click. On click, that specific button should stay the clicked color and only change back to normal once a different button is clicked. Clicked color should also not change again on mouse enter or mouse leave. Should be flat buttons.

Thanks

Comment: Radiobuttons are the normal UI gadget for this.  ToolStripMenuItem.CheckState in the case of a menu.  There is no particular advice if you want to use regular buttons, certainly not "best", just do it the way you like it.

Answer (score 0):

change background of all buttons to default on click.

Then apply the Required backrgound to the button which triggered the click event by using the `sender` variable of the event